# latin1 not available in character set in Phpmyadmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, latin1

Hi I am doing this tutorial about SQL. I added `$cfg['UploadDir']` = 'c:Files'; in my 
config.inc.php, and import it to phpmyadmin. The problem is that I cannot find latin1 as character set. In one of the question from stackOverflow: [Cannot select Latin-1 as the character set in PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372610/cannot-select-latin-1-as-the-character-set-in-phpmyadmin) Someone mentioned that

> Latin 1 is ISO 8859-1, is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/charset/):

> ISO 8859-1 character set overview
>
> The following tables give all characters which are available in the
>   ISO Latin 1 character set.

Basically, Yes.